# Page doesn't scale 100% on Chrome Dev Tools devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, google-chrome-devtools

The page done on bootstrap seems to be not scaling 100% on google chrome dev tools devices mode, regarding the responsive design.

It seems to leave couple pixels on each side.

The meta tag is 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">`,
same without "shrink-to-fit=no".

I include the image below:

[image]

Is there anything that could be done to make page scale 100%, not leaving sides out of the browser width?

Comment: Can you show some of your html structure, would give a better idea and possible reasons as to why it's breaking.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your html code is not per Bootstrap way of organizing with container and row classes. Can you share the html code you are using for the said page?

Comment: I actually noticed where the problem was. All bootstrap .row classes add padding-left and padding-right 15px, that's why the container is streched out.